# MongoDb Data Migration Tools

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongobee

I am working with Sprint Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and MongoDB 3.6 and using mongobee as a database migration tool.
Now, I have to upgrade to MongoDB 4.2 as per requirements and can't use mongobee as definition of indexes has changed and it is no longer supported.

I am looking for alternatives for a data migration tool compatible with spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE and MongoDB 4.2

I tried mongock but v3.3.2 is not supporting Mongo 4.2. Any suggestions on any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Last Mongock's version is 4.0.8.alpha. It's alpha because we are still adding features, but it's pretty stable. We are thinking to turn to production in the next weeks.  Among other features it's support MongoDB 4.x. Does't provide transactionable migrations yet, but it will in the next releases.

This version is used in the next JHipster release and other companies are testing it and no major issues.

There is not official documentation yet, but [this sample project](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock-integration-tests/tree/master/mongock-spring-v5/mongock-spring5-springdata3-it) is a pretty illustrative one.

I suggest you to give it a try and let us know if you have any issue. We are very responsive.

Comment: The link to this sample project is broken ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try Liquiase MongoDB Extension: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb
You can find a Spring Boot example: https://github.com/alexandru-slobodcicov/liquibase-nosql-quickstart